# Symfony/Twig absolute_url generates wrong url

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-3.4

The app gets installed on our integration-server  + a folder for the branch (http://integration/feature-abc/)

**Symfony 2.8 behavior**

`asset('/image.png')` => generates `/feature-abc/image.png`

`absolute_url(asset('/image.png'))` => generates `http://integration/feature-abc/image.png`

**Symfony 3.4 behavior**

`asset('/image.png')` =>  `/feature-abc/image.png`

`absolute_url(asset('/image.png'))` => generates `http://integration/image.png`

The feature-folder (/feature-abc/) is missing when using absolute_url

Before upgrading from symfony 2.8 to 3.4 the urls were generated corretly.

Anyone has a clue why this is happening?

Comment: I'm actually surprised about how it worked in the first place. Probably a default web assets folder in your assetic configuration

Comment: May sounds stupid, but why is there a slash before your file name?! shouldn't it be `'image.png'` and not `/image.png'`?

Answer (score 1):

[Preciel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499759/symfony-twig-absolute-url-generates-wrong-url#comment83993598_48499759) was totally right. Omitting the leading slash will make it work again. I'm just wondering why it works without a flaw on 2.8.

Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your config dump?

```
bin/console debug:config framework
```

It doesn't seem that anything has changed here. Also check the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/configuration/framework.html#base-path%20'docs') for base_path, if it's set right.